# Cassandra secondary index issue - returning zero rows

Tags: cassandra

I have a problem in that a secondary index is returning zero rows in cassandra:

I'm following along the getting started docs:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/getting_started/doc/getting_started/gettingStartedCQL.html

Based on that I have the following cassandra script

```
/* hello.cql */
drop keyspace test;
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
use test;
CREATE TABLE users (  user_id int PRIMARY KEY,   fname text,   lname text);
DESCRIBE TABLES;
INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname) 
  VALUES (1745, 'john', 'smith');
INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname) 
  VALUES (1744, 'john', 'doe');
INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname) 
  VALUES (1746, 'john', 'smith');
SELECT * FROM users;
CREATE INDEX ON users (lname);

/* These queries both return 0 rows ??? */
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = 'smith';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = 'doe';
```

However...

```
cqlsh < hello.cql 

users


 user_id | fname | lname
---------+-------+-------
    1745 |  john | smith
    1744 |  john |   doe
    1746 |  john | smith

(3 rows)

(0 rows)

(0 rows)
```

This should be straightforward -- am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the 2 `SELECT` queries to return results would mean that the `CREATE INDEX` would execute synchronously **and** it will **only** return after all existing data would be indexed.

If you change the order in the script to have the index defined before you insert any data, I'd expect the 2 selects to return results.

Comment: Yes, I thought I had tried that but I must have fat-fingered that attempt.  Tried it again and you're right.  Datastax doc bug though.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cassandra 2.1.0, I get results regardless of whether the index is created before or after data is inserted.

```
    Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
    [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
    Use HELP for help.
    cqlsh> 
    cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
    cqlsh> use test;
    cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE users (  user_id int PRIMARY KEY,   fname text,   lname text);
    cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname) 
        ...   VALUES (1745, 'john', 'smith');
    cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname) 
        ...   VALUES (1744, 'john', 'doe');
    cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname) 
        ...   VALUES (1746, 'john', 'smith');
    cqlsh:test> CREATE INDEX ON users (lname);
    cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = 'smith';

     user_id | fname | lname
    ---------+-------+-------
        1745 |  john | smith
        1746 |  john | smith

    (2 rows)

    cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname = 'doe';

     user_id | fname | lname
    ---------+-------+-------
        1744 |  john |   doe

    (1 rows)
```

Comment: And running your commands in a hello.cql script also returns 3 rows, 2 rows, and 1 rows.

Comment: Fair enough -- could be platform or version specific.  Will post specific version info when I get back to that box for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the platform and version info for my installation:

```
john@piggies:~/Dropbox/source/casandra$ nodetool -h localhost version
ReleaseVersion: 2.0.10
john@piggies:~/Dropbox/source/casandra$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
john@piggies:~/Dropbox/source/casandra$ ^C
john@piggies:~/Dropbox/source/casandra$
```

Comment: This problem doesn't exist on 2.0.10 tarball installation or any previous 2.0 tarball installations. My attempts just now to install the 2.0.10 package on ubuntu in the cloud failed, so I can't check your platform. Is it possible to wipe the slate clean and retry?

Comment: Correction--there was a slightly similar problem on 2.0.5 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6517, but it was resolved. If you're willing, please try, nodetool rebuild_index test users