# Why does my Cassandra SELECT WHERE statement return 0 rows?

Tags: csv, select, cassandra

I am trying to query by USERID, which is indexed, and part of a composite key, on a table with ~1000 rows:

```
create table MYTABLE (
DATE timestamp,
USERID text,
FIRST_NAME text,
LAST_NAME text,
primary key (DATE, USERID));

create index on mytable(userid);
```

The following works fine:

```
select userid from mytable limit 5;

 userid
-------------
   "ID0003"
   "ID0004"
   "ID0005"
   "ID0006"
   "ID0007"

(5 rows)
```

But if I query by one of these IDs, I get 0 rows

```
select * from mytable where userid='ID0003' limit 5 ALLOW FILTERING;
(0 rows)
```

Why am I getting 0 rows? I have an index set up, so [that is not the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965124/cassandra-secondary-index-issue-returning-zero-rows).

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.10 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

Comment: Are those `"` quotes literally part of your records? If so, you'd need to do `userid='"ID0003"'` instead. `ID0003 != "ID0003"`

Comment: @MarcB: Nope, just tried it.

Comment: well, check for other things, like invisible/whitespace chars. e.g. `'[space]foo'` is not equal to `'foo'`

Comment: I've just set up an identical table and index and the query works fine. Can you try rebuilding your index.

Comment: @MarcB never mind, you were right. I have quotation marks *and* whitespace, which is why it didn't work at first...Quotation marks are only special characters when loading from CSV when the field has a newline

Answer (score 0):

It was an artifact of how CSV imports work. My data comes from a CSV which uses quotation marks as a special character. So my rows looked like `"2014-09-15", "ID0547" , "Firstname 0547" , "Lastname 0547"`.

Older documentation states that [quotation marks are only special characters when a field has a newline](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/COPY). Newer documentation does not note this, but the behavior remains. My IDs were therefore in the format `[SPACE][DOUBLEQUOTE]ID0547[DOUBLEQUOTE][SPACE]`.